# Extract latest tag version from Git in V1.0.0 format

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I want to extract the number of latest version of a Git repository. This what I've done so far:

```
#--- Checking out latest tag
printf "%bChecking out tag...%b\n" "${YELLOW}" "${GRAY}"
LATEST_TAG=$(git describe --tags)
printf "\nChecking out tag %b${LATEST_TAG}%b\n" "${YELLOW}" "${GRAY}"
git checkout -b V${LATEST_TAG%-*} ${LATEST_TAG}
```

My problem is that if `git describe --tags` returns something like this `1.0.0-39-gf8f8306` I end up creating a branch `V1.0.0-39`.

What I want is to create a branch named `V1.0.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Add it as an answer please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s a bit of a secret,<sup>*</sup> but you can use `--abbrev=0`:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

---

<sup>*</sup>[`git help describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#git-describe---abbrevltngt) mentions it, but you have to know where to look:

> `--abbrev=<n>`
>
> […] An `<n>` of 0 will suppress long format, only showing the closest tag.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with `git describe` on GitHub Actions, namely: "fatal: No tags can describe '160ef4560d8855c9c05f4cae207baeb71b7791f3'." Which apparently has something to do with the entire repo not being available.

But I found another solution that works and doesn't have this issue:

```
git tag --sort=-refname --list "v[0-9]*" | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`:

```
LATEST_TAG=$(git describe --tags | awk -F - '{print $1}')
```

Comment: Works but I will take Biffen answer cause it's the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

In your line

`git checkout -b V${LATEST_TAG%-*} ${LATEST_TAG}`

you can double up the % symbol which will match the longest string starting with a - rather than the shortest which is what a single % does.

eg `git checkout -b V${LATEST_TAG%%-*} ${LATEST_TAG}`

You can see a full list of parameter expansions here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: Works but I will take Biffen answer